# Objective-C versus C, which one is a better language on the Mac?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, macos

What is better to program on Macintosh? Is it worth it learning Objective-C along the Cocoa API?

I'm thinking about building a desktop editor for online applications such as Content Management Systems and was wondering what was the less painful path.

Comment: Cocoa is not a language, I think you mean Objective-C.

Comment: @DasBoot edited question. @James McNellis Added some context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. If you want to write software for Mac OS X or iOS learning objective C and cocoa goes without saying.  The Cocoa framework makes your life easier.  Of course C can also be included in your code if needed.  Its usually a good idea to at least have an understanding of core fundamentals in C when learning Objective-C.

finally, this question is subjective and not really the proper place to be asking it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Programming Mac in straight C is on the way out. There was quite a scandal recently about the fact that the C-based Carbon toolkit was not ported to 64 bits. Cocoa was ported. So there are signals coming from Cupertino that they're going to phase out Carbon eventually.

Comment: Carbon is a very popular Mac OS API written in C?

Comment: Carbon was the API Apple created to help developers move from OS 9 to OS X. It was written in C and was popular in early versions of OS X, but has died off a little and Apple is helping push it out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting Apps for Mac and iOS? Objective C should make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build GUI applications, you definitely want to learn objective-c. Apple is removing support for much of the Carbon API, and it isn't supported at all for 64 bit applications.

If you are not going to build GUI applications, I would still suggest learning objective-c, even though it isn't necessary. Objective-c is easy to learn if you already know C, and I find that I can build an application much faster using it. Apple has made a lot of things much easier in their objective-c APIs, and they are kind of moving toward even deeper integration of the language.